# Attempting to convert an XSD to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xsd

I am attempting to convert an XSD to JSON using the XSD2JSON2 package. I have tried the below, but the users.json file is not created

```
var xsd2json = require('xsd2json2').xsd2json;
var fs = require('fs');

xsd2json('users.xsd', (err, jsonSchema) => {
    fs.writeFile('users.json', jsonSchema, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('JSON schema created')
    });
});
```

I tried the above after getting a 'callback not defined' issue with XSD2JSON2's usage code:

```
var xsd2json = require('xsd2json2').xsd2json;
var fs = require('fs');

xsd2json('./users.xsd', function(err, jsonSchema) {
    fs.writeFile('./users.json', jsonSchema, callback);
});
```

I am currently learning JS (as you can probably tell) so any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: In your first code, xsd2json's first callback parameter should be an `error` right? So it should be like `xsd2json('users.xsd', (err, jsonSchema) => {`. Haven't really used this before, but I am just wondering if you've tried that.

Comment: Yes, same outcome - no users.json file created. I have amended the code in original post, too.

Comment: Is there any error message given there? Like a write permission issue or anything?